# Requesting data through GET request to express server returns document instead of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, instagram-api

I am trying to use the Instagram api to retrieve some data. The problem is that when sending the data back from the express server to the client, the client doesn't log the data to the console but instead I just get an html document displayed with only one line:

```
{"urls":["https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/21042827_129089451063629_713103852630441984_n.jpg"]}
```

Client side:

```
$('#retrieve_photos_btn').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/retrieve_photos",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

App.js:

```
app.get('/retrieve_photos', function(req, res){
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='+access_token
    }
    request(options, function(error, resp, body){
        if(error) console.log("Retrieving photos failed: " + error);
        var body_parsed = JSON.parse(body);

        var media_urls = [];
        // Iterate over all received media
        for(var i = 0; i < body_parsed.data.length; i++){
            media_urls.push(body_parsed.data[i].images.low_resolution.url);
        }
        res.send( JSON.stringify( {urls: media_urls} ) );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I already found the problem: the button was inside a form like this:

```
form#retrieve_photos_insta_form(method='GET', action='retrieve_photos')
    button.btn.btn-primary#retrieve_photos_btn Retrieve
```

So when clicking the button, the call to `/retrieve_photos` would be done through the form, instead of the javascript code I wrote in the question.

Changing the code so that there is no form and the button directly triggers the javascript code fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try `res.json({urls: media_urls})`. This will set the header for you automatically.

Instead of

`res.send( JSON.stringify({urls: media_urls} ) )`

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately the problem still persists.

Comment: hmm. after you click the button, what is the url in your address bar (in the browser)? has it changed to `/retrieve_photos`. Sounds like your whole page might have been reloaded as `/retrieve_photos`

Comment: Thanks, I already found the problem. But yes the whole page got reloaded as `/retrieve_photos` since the button was inside a form with the attribute `action='retrieve_photos'`